# css min-width doesn't work in googlechrome

Tags: html, css

I designed a page with header and footer and body tags. for header and footer I set the width:100%; and I set a min-width: 1024px; in firefox and IE it work well and when  minimize the window it keeps its minimom size but in googlechrome minwidth doesnt work and when I minimize the window header and footer only have width of the window and when I scroll to the right there is white space and it doesnt extend 100% but for the content all things is ok.
I put some of html and css code here.

```
<div id="f-page">
  <div style="width:100%; min-width:1024px; z-index:800;
   background-image:url(fimages/headerbg.gif); height:120px;"> 
   <center>
    <div id="f-header"></div>
   </center>
   </div>
   <div id="f-mypage"></div>
    <div id="f-footer">
     <center>
    <br />
    <h6> some text</h6>
     </center>            
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#f-footer
        {
           height:70px;  min-width:1024px;
           background-image:url('../f-images/ffoot.png');
           background-repeat:repeat-x;
        }
#f-header {width:1024px;height:120px;z-index:1000;}
#f-page {margin:0 auto;}
#f-mypage
        {
          width:1004px;height:auto; background-color:White; margin-top:10px;
          padding-bottom:30px;border:1px solid #cccfcb;
          -moz-box-shadow:5px 0 5px -5px #333,-5px 0 5px -5px #333;
          -webkit-box-shadow:5px 0 5px -5px #333,-5px 0 5px -5px #333;
          box-shadow:5px 0 5px -5px #333,-5px 0 5px -5px #333; 
        }
```

thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Min-width is working fine in chrome.

Perhaps you need to set at background to see the effect:

```
 #f-footer
    {
      height:70px;  min-width:1024px;
         background-image:url('../f-images/ffoot.png'); background-repeat:repeat-x;
      background: red;
    }
```

Working fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/basarat/uPTSd/

Comment: In jsfiddle every thing is ok but at my code that has more details it doesn't work, I don't know where is the problem.

Comment: Any chance f a link to your site, @Somy J? This is a pretty standard setup.